# How can I preset sprite positions in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, location, sprite

I am currently building a playing card game.  As usual, the first few steps were to build an array of cards, shuffle them, and then Deal them to each player (there are 4).  I want the cards to appear in front of each player in a "fan" setup, much like if you have 15 cards in your hand how you would spread them out equally.  I am very new to COCOS2d and I'm having some trouble figuring out this component.

My question really is this- how can I code my cocos2d project so that the playing cards dealt go to pre-determined positions in front of each player?  I want the cards to appear fan'd out in front of each player.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For each card, create a CCNode object and add the card sprite as child of the node. Position the node where the bottom of the cards should align and rotate around.

Next, position the sprite to be offset vertically from its CCNode parent. In other words, set its position to (0, 100) for example. It should be more than half the card's height, perhaps two thirds. Then rotate the CCNode parent, this will rotate the card as well with the position of the CCNode being the center of rotation.

Repeat this for all cards in sequence and you can lay them out as a fan from left to right, or right to left depending on the order you add the node+sprite.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please expand a bit on this (be gentle, I'm new).  I think the coding side of things is what's throwing me.  For example, if all my cards are set in an NSMutableArray "cards", how would I go about creating the Nodes with random cards each time?  I'm wanting 5 random cards to be dealt to each of the 4 positions, so my mind explodes when I try to sync up a dealing animation with CCNode objects loading offscreen then appearing on screen.